# Как установить порядок вызова Filters (Servlet API) без `web.xml`

Tags: java, servlet, filter, web.xml

Каким образом (параметром,аннотацией и т.п.) можно установить порядок вызовов фильтров перед сервлетом, при этом не применяя `web.xml`, **Spring** и т.д.?

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/page</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/page</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Коротко:** порядок следования фильтров в цепи `FiltersChain` указывается в методе `init` первого фильтра.

Получаем ServletContext:

```java
ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
```

далее всем последующим фильтрам добавляем маппинг:

```java
FilterRegistration registration2 = context.getFilterRegistration("Filter2");
registration2.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "*.html", "/games/*", "/blog/*");
registration2.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "ViewCode");

FilterRegistration registration22 = context.getFilterRegistration("Filter22");
registration22.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "*.html", "/games/*", "/blog/*");
registration22.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "ViewCode");
```

---

**Подробно:** пример

AbstractFilter.java

```java
public abstract class AbstractFilter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();

        ArrayList<String> filtersChain = (ArrayList<String>) httpSession.getAttribute("filtersChain");

        if (filtersChain == null) {
            filtersChain = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if (!filtersChain.contains(this.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
            filtersChain.add(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        httpSession.setAttribute("filtersChain", filtersChain);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Filter.java

```java
@WebFilter(filterName = "Filter",
        urlPatterns = {"*.html", "/games/*", "/blog/*"},
        servletNames = "ViewCode")
public class Filter extends AbstractFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();

        FilterRegistration registration2 = context.getFilterRegistration("Filter2");
        registration2.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "*.html", "/games/*", "/blog/*");
        registration2.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "ViewCode");

        FilterRegistration registration22 = context.getFilterRegistration("Filter22");
        registration22.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "*.html", "/games/*", "/blog/*");
        registration22.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "ViewCode");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Ваш код здесь

        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Filter2.java

```java
@WebFilter(filterName = "Filter2")
public class Filter2 extends AbstractFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Ваш код здесь

        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Filter22.java

```java
@WebFilter(filterName = "Filter22")
public class Filter22 extends AbstractFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Ваш код здесь

        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Servlet.java

```java
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/index.html"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doResponse(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doResponse(request, response);
    }

    private void doResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ArrayList<String> filtersChain = (ArrayList<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("filtersChain");

        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();

        printWriter.append("<html>\n");
        printWriter.append("<head>\n");
        printWriter.append("<title>Hello World</title>\n");
        printWriter.append("</head>\n");
        printWriter.append("<body>\n");
        printWriter.append("<p>Hello World</p>\n");

        if (filtersChain != null) {
            for (String filter : filtersChain) {
                printWriter.append("<p>" + filter + "</p>\n");
            }
        }

        printWriter.append("</body>\n");
        printWriter.append("</html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "Filter",
        urlPatterns = {"*.html", "/site/*", "/blog/*"},
        servletNames = "special")
public class Filter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Ваш код здесь..

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: если у нас есть FiltrA, FiltrB, FiltrC, каким параметром определить порядок вызова фильтров к примеру 1. FiltrC / 2. FiltrB / 3. FiltrA не используя web.xml?